# Unable to get UISearchController in my navigation bar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a main view controller, it has a fullscreen `UITableView` which is populated by values from Firebase and a TabBarController below. All the code for the `UITableView` is handled programmatically. I need to add two options: Firstly, a search bar to query the results and a filter option for the various categories to fetch from Firebase.

Here is my updated code from the `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class PostTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()

    var searchController : UISearchController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            switchStoryboard()
        }

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!

        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.reloadData()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // displays tableview

        let scb = self.searchController.searchBar
        scb.tintColor = UIColor.white
        scb.placeholder = "SEARCH"
        scb.barTintColor = UIColor.white

        if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            textfield.textColor = UIColor.green
            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
            searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
        }
        definesPresentationContext = true


        observePosts()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add variable of `UISearchController`

```
var searchController : UISearchController!
```

& then add code in `viewDidLoad`

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // displays tableview

    let scb = self.searchController.searchBar
    scb.tintColor = UIColor.white
    scb.placeholder = "SEARCH"
    scb.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        textfield.textColor = UIColor.greenColor
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor
    }
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: `Cannot assign value of type 'PostTable' to type 'UISearchResultsUpdating?'` on line 3, it's not working when I cast it as anything else

Comment: you need to add delegate for `UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating`

Comment: The search bar is not being displayed, the whole navigation bar is of the colour green.

Comment: can you share the SS of output & your relevant code? & you can remove the color for navBar as updated in code

Comment: Here's the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/YM4arm4) of the output, I will update the code above in a minute

Comment: have you added NavigationBar manually or set up the Navigation controller?

Comment: I've added the NavigationController, TabBarController but not added the navigation bar. All the UI components are coming directly from the code.

Answer (score 0):

An UITabbarController does not have a UINavigationController so it doesn't have a UINavigationBar.

So you could do:

- Add a cell to your TableView to act like a search bar
- Add a Navigationbar to the ViewController
- Add a custom View to your View to act as a container

There may be more options, just want to point you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController

            // Make the search bar always visible.
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            // For iOS 10 and earlier, place the search controller's search bar in the table view's header.
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }

        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // The default is true.
    }
```